# How to rewrite sql with multi-subqueries in Hive

Tags: hive, subquery

Here is a SQL with multi-subqueries for GreenPlum. Unfortunately I have to migrate SQL to Hive, I don't know how to deal with these subqueries in WHERE clause.

```
select 
    t.ckid , t.prod_id , t.supp_num , t.wljhdh , 
    sum(t.sssl) as zmkc , max(t.dj) as dj
from 
    %s t
where
    exists (select 1 
            from dw_stage.wms_c_wlsjd w 
            where w.lydjh = t.wljhdh and w.lzztflag='上架确认'
              and (ckid , kqid) in (select ckid , kqid 
                                    from dw_stage.jcxx_kqxx 
                                    where kqytsxid in ('2','3'))
        )
        and (t.ckid,t.supp_num)  in (select cgck_stock_id,vndr_code from madfrog.cfg_vendor_dist where status=1 and send_method=2 and upper(purch_warehouse_type)='F')
        and supp_num not in (select distinct vndr_code as supp_no from madfrog.cfg_vendor_dist where status=1 and send_method in (4,5))
    group by t.ckid , t.prod_id , t.supp_num , t.wljhdh
```

Thank you for your tips.

Comment: hiveClient version is 1.2.1

Comment: have you tried in hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to convert the `subquery` and the `in clause` to

> Left Outer Join

Focusing on the structure:

```
select <cols list> 
from <tabname> t
left outer join dw_stage.wms_c_wlsjd w 
 on w.lydjh = t.wljhdh 
where w.lzztflag='上架确认'
```

The

```
((t.ckid,t.supp_num)  in (select .. )
```

and

```
supp_num not in (select distinct vndr_code as supp_no
```

will **also** need to be rewritten as an outer joins.

You can find more information about using outer join's in my answer to this other question here:  [Hive command to execute NOT IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880124/hive-command-to-execute-not-in-clause/20885465#20885465)

Comment: Thanks! So far I haven't found other way to solve this kind of problems, I'll try your solution.